# possible to modifer the properties of windows in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, macos

These are windows besides those that belong to the application. For example, how could I change the title of an open application, for example, TextEdit

Comment: Wait, you want to do what? Like change the name of an app that has nothing to do with the app your currently in? I don't think apple will let you do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use mach_inject and mach_override to load code into the target application and then simply use the Objective-C API's to access the window.

You could also try using applescript, but no idea if or how that is done.